# Join two aggregates from two separate tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am looking for a way to "join" results of two queries.
Expected result is one row with two aggregates `SumValueA` and `SumValueB`.

Each of those two queries returns only one row.
`JOIN` will not work as both tables do not have any data in common.

I am using SQL Server 2017.

Query 1:

```
SELECT Sum(ValueA) AS SumValueA
FROM dbo.TableA
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT Sum(ValueB) AS SumValueB
FROM dbo.TableB
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  (SELECT Sum(ValueA) FROM dbo.TableA) AS SumValueA,
        (SELECT Sum(ValueB) FROM dbo.TableB) AS SumValueB
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `cross join`.

```
SELECT sumvalueA, sumvalueB
  FROM (SELECT Sum(ValueA) AS SumValueA
          FROM dbo.TableA) a
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT Sum(ValueB) AS SumValueB
FROM dbo.TableB)
```

A cross join displays all rows from subquery a with all rows from subquery b. This results in a cartesian product.